# _sql_constraints not working in Odoo v10

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I have a model defined as-

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    _name = 'model_name'
    student_id = fields.Many2one('op.student', 'Student')
```

I want that student should be unique. So i added -

```
    _sql_constraints = [
         ('student_unique',
         'UNIQUE(student_id)', 'Some message!')
    ]
```

but it's not doing anything. I can still select same student and save the form.

I want when i click `create` button, students for which record has already been saved should not be shown.

What can i do to achieve this??

Comment: I think you need to delete all the records from that model first.
because it only applies when there is no existing data in the model.

Comment: Thanks, working now. But that same student is still visible in that dropdown list. The thing which is working is that, forms aren't saving for the same student. I want student should not be even visible in the dropdown. Please suggest a way.

Comment: you can use the dynamic domain on that field student_id to display only records which are not there in any of the records.

Comment: can you please brief it?

Comment: is it worked..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this below domain function in your field, I'm sure you will get your required output.

```py
student_id = fields.Many2one('op.student',domain=lambda self: self.get_not_existing_student_id(), string='Student')

@api.model
def get_not_existing_student_id(self):
    self.env.cr.execute("select id from op_student where id not in (select student_id from model_name)")
    datas = self.env.cr.fetchall()
    student_ids = []
    for record in datas:
        student_ids.append(record[0])
    return [('id','in',student_ids)]
```

**Other Way:**

```
student_id = fields.Many2one('op.student',string='Student')
```

put it in a view like:

```
<field name="student_id" context="{'find_existed':1}" options="{'no_create':1}"/>
```

Then inherit the method name_get() in op.student model like this.

```
class op_student(models.Model):
    _inherit ="op.student"

    @api.multi
    def name_get(self):
        if self._context.get("find_existed",False): 
            self.env.cr.execute("select id from op_student where id not in (select student_id from model_name)")
            datas = self.env.cr.fetchall()
            student_ids = []
            for record in datas:
                student_ids.append(record[0])
            for student in self:
                if student in student_ids:
                    res.append((student.id,student.name))
        else:
            res=super(op_student,self).name_get()
        return res
```

Comment: It works only once. I went to the form and clicked student dropdown, it showed students according to the code. I selected a student and saved the form. Now when i again create another record and try to select student, same list is showing but after refreshing it is again working.

Comment: did you used any widget on field student_id in view?

Comment: First _sql_constraints  are executed by postgreSQL engine if didn't work this means something wrong with you data that prevent postgres from creating the constrains

I think @Viki Chavada answer is very good answer but as you said this domain is loaded only one time so instead of using @api.model and domain keyword use onchange event it's better onchange is always called when the field is changed or when the from is loaded again `@api.onchange('student_id')`

Comment: @VikiChavada NO, nothing is used. Its a many2one field with no_create = True

Comment: `return {'domain' : {'student_id': [same_domain_in_answer]}}`

Comment: Thank you @CherifOdoo, I updated my answer check it out it is the another way to do it.

Comment: Yes i always forget that m2o calls this method lol nice thinking